# SSRS/Report Builder - Export to Word Shows Hidden Rows

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, report-builder2.0

SSRS and Report Builder drive me absolutely crazy at times.  In this instance, I have a report where I have **2 rows which are hidden** if there are no images attached to that item.  When exporting to PDF it works perfectly, however **when I export to Word**, the 18 page report is now 30 because it is showing the "should-be-hidden" rows.

Because the rows hold images, I can't shrink it since I need the images (when they are there) to fit proportionally into the 2in high row.

I've tried changing the height from inches to points, as well as a few other things and nothing seems to tell Word to hide these rows.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apply the "Hidden" font property to the entire row.